# How to pass a template lambda to a function and use it with different types

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, template-argument-deduction, generic-lambda

I have this code inherited from old C++ time using macros. I'm currently replacing it, and I'm at the point where some constructs need to be factored.

Typically, I have this:

```
if(condition)
{
    fun1(fun2(arguments, arg1)); // let's say arg1 is a vector of doubles
}
else
{
    fun1(fun2(arguments, arg2)); // let's say arg2 is a double
}
```

several times. `fun1()` has a different set of arguments depending on `fun2()` argument types, and I could have `arg1` and `arg2` there as well (the true code actually has several layers of `if`s with each time a different set of types, several additional layers of functions inside each branch).

I'd like to factor this one out in a function that can take a template lambda like this:

```
[&](auto arg) { fun1(fun2(arguments, arg));}
```

Now, the issue is that this is templated, so I can't turn it into a `std::function`, so I don't know what kind of argument I should use to create my function:

```
void dispatch(bool condition, const std::vector<double>& arg1, double arg2, ???? lambda)
{
    if(condition)
    {
        lambda(arg1);
    }
    else
    {
        lambda(arg2);
    }
}
```

Is there such an option in C++17? or even C++20?

Comment: What is wrong with making `dispatch` a template as well?

Comment: Why don't you write `fun1(fun2(arguments, {arg2}));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, the issue is that this is templated, so I can't turn it into a `std::function`, so I don't know what kind of argument I should use to create my function

What about simply as follows ?

```
template <typename F>
void dispatch(bool condition, const std::vector<double>& arg1, double arg2, F lambda)
```

I mean... you can see a lambda function almost as syntactic sugar for an object of a class with an `operator()` (a template `operator()` in case of 
a generic-lambda).

So you can intercept a lambda simply through the template type of the class.

Maybe you can accept it as const reference (`F const & lambda`), if `lambda` is not mutable, to avoid unnecessary copies.

> Is there such an option in C++17? or even C++20?

Should works starting from C++14.
Before C++14, generic lambda are unavailable (but you can substitute them with explicit classes with template `operator()`s).

Comment: This is the way.  Don't pay the expense for a `std::function`, just take the function object directly.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, as simple as that... looking at macro for too long shuts down the brain apparently.